# hyperref links not working with pdfcrop in latexmkrc (in Overleaf)

Tags: hyperref, overleaf, latexmk, pdfcrop

I like to crop white margins to save screen space while working in Overleaf. I use `latexmkrc` file with the following code:
`$pdflatex = 'pdflatex %O %S; pdfcrop --margins "20" %B.pdf %B-c.pdf; mv %B-c.pdf %B.pdf';`

However, `pdfcrop` seems to disable hyperref links. Without the `pdfcrop` command, the hyperlinks work. With `pdfcrop`, the hyperlinks are not clickable anymore (even though the links are still colored by hyperref).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\begin{document}
\section{Section one}\label{sec:one}
This is Section~\ref{sec:one}.
\end{document}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to make both `hyperref` and `pdfcrop` work? Alternatively, is there another way to crop the white margins away while being able to use `hyperref` links?

Remark: To rule out other issues with the `latexmkrc` code, I tried with
`$pdflatex = 'pdflatex %O %S; mv %B.pdf %B-c.pdf; mv %B-c.pdf %B.pdf';`, which works fine.

Comment: use the geometry package to specify the margins you want, you should not have to generate the wrong size then crop it

Comment: pdfcrop works by reinserting the pdf as picture. This looses links.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah, I see, so there is no way how to make it work with pdfcrop then.

Comment: well one can reinsert links later, but this is not trivial.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Changing just the margins would make a wide textwidth which is undesirable — I want things to be typeset as in the document with the margins. But I guess geometry allows to change all sizes, right? So if I just make margins 0 or very small, and textwidth as it should be in the final a4, everything should be the same when I then change it to the actual a4 layout — or do I need to redefine some other widths too?

Comment: @OnDragi why would you need to change \textwidth?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, sorry, my mistake, I thought `\textwidth` gets larger when changing margins, which is not the case. For a4paper I can do, e.g., `\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-2.5cm}`, `\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-2.5cm}`, `\addtolength{\paperwidth}{-5cm}` to achieve what I want. This seems to work nicely, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pdfcrop` reinserts the pdf as a picture, so the hyperlinks are lost, as pointed out by @UlrikeFischer.

An alternative way to crop out the white margins is to make use of the `geometry` package, as pointed by @DavidCarlisle. Instead of making latex generate the full page and then cropping it, we generate already smaller page by latex. We can use, e.g., the following (values for `a4paper`):

```
\usepackage{geometry}

\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-2.5cm}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-2.5cm}
\addtolength{\paperwidth}{-5cm}
```